No exception-message-string for ConnectionException
Is it normal that a ConnectionException does not have a message-text??
Is null generally allowed for the message?
Using OpenJDK17 and OpenJDK11.
try
{
    HttpRequest httpreq = HttpRequest.newBuilder ().uri (URI.create ("http://blabla.blabla.blabla")).build ();
    HttpClient httpclnt = HttpClient.newBuilder ().build ();
    HttpResponse <String> httpresp = httpclnt.send (httpreq, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString ());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println ("EXCEPTION: " + e + "   -    " + e.getMessage ());
}          

Output is
EXCEPTION: java.net.ConnectException   -    null


There is nothing afaik to enforce what message is set. But it's a good illustration of why you should use printStackTrace()

yes, the ConnectionException does not have a message text because the exception itself is self-explanatory
you can try to handle the null in the code:
try {
    HttpRequest httpreq = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("http://blabla.blabla.blabla")).build();
    HttpClient httpclnt = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    HttpResponse<String> httpresp = httpclnt.send(httpreq, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    String message = e.getMessage();
    if (message == null) {
        message = "No message available";
    }
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + e + "   -    " + message);
}

